# Cannot read property 'bcrypt' of undefined with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am following the Basic Tutorial to use TurkServer, but I get an error from the beginning.

The error I get when I run: meteor `--settings settings.json`

```
W20160615-01:19:27.320(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20160615-01:19:27.406(-4)? (STDERR) ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.3.b5ue33++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20160615-01:19:27.406(-4)? (STDERR) 
throw(ex);
W20160615-01:19:27.407(-4)? (STDERR) 
     ^
W20160615-01:19:27.407(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'bcrypt' of undefined
W20160615-01:19:27.407(-4)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer.Accounts._checkPassword (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:68:33)
W20160615-01:19:27.407(-4)? (STDERR)     at ~/interactiveEstimation/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/mizzao_turkserver.js:4881:18
W20160615-01:19:27.407(-4)? (STDERR)     at ~/interactiveEstimation/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:298:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

My settings file:

```
{
  "turkserver": {
    "adminPassword": "mmaatouq95",
    "experiment": {
      "limit": {
      }
    },
    "mturk": {
      "accessKeyId": "AKIAJDDHTM3IRYMWUX7Q",
      "secretAccessKey": "eeTud7Gml3Yz6XD9gWLUZzsJokoie2rEq"
    }
  }
}
```

It seems general problem with Meteor, not with TurkServer (the project files https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppgbuwv4k3imbt5/interactiveEstimation.zip):

Comment: It seems like your user was not created properly. Try to delete the admin user from the database and rerun the server. Does it change anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When examining your project, your user does not contain a `bcrypt` entry.

This indicates that it was not created properly and this leads to the described error.

If you delete the user from the `meteor mongo` database console and restart the server, the user should be created properly and the issue should be resolved.